# Expression comprehension in function argument

Tags: python

Why is this code

```py
sum(x for x in range(10))
```

valid? Why encasing `x for x in range(10)` in square brackets is not necessary?

Comment: See [Generator Expressions vs List Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

Comment: strictly speaking, neither is necessary here, `sum(range(10))`

Comment: @khelwood, so ```sum(x for x in range(10))``` is implicitely converted to ```sum(<generator expression>)```? Am I getting it right? Then how reliable is this behavior?

Comment: Completely reliable. It's part of the language. If you write `(<x> for <y> in <z>)`, you've written a generator expression.

Comment: @khelwood, you may be right but I raise the same concern as I did it an answer below. Surely `sum(X)` means `X` given to the `sum` function. If that's the case, `X` is `x for x in range(10)` rather than the generator `(x for x in range(10))`.

Comment: When you write `(x for x in range(10))` you are writing `(generator expression)`. So `sum` receives the generator expression as its argument.

Comment: @khelwood, my question was about omitting round brackets. Apparently it is permitted for the sake of simplicity in case of sole argument (I actually got a special syntax error after trying it with function with multiple argument).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this has pretty much already been said in comments, but for posterity: [Section 6.2.8](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) of the (Python 3.8.0) docs state that "[t]he parentheses can be omitted on calls with only one argument. See section [Calls](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) for details."

Edit: And, for completeness, the "Calls" section goes on to say that the actual parameters of a call can be either a comma-separated list of parameters, or a single `comprehension`, which is the `x for x in ...` stuff without brackets.

Answer (score 1):

It creates a generator expression.

```
>>> nums = (x for x in range(4))
>>> nums
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001E52747B2B0>
>>> next(nums)
0
>>> next(nums)
1
>>> next(nums)
2
>>> next(nums)
3
>>> next(nums)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

What is a generator? It basically doesn't execute unless it is asked to execute. A list comprehension will first create a `list` and then pass that `list` to the `sum` function.

Getting rid of the square brackets makes it a generator which will send each generated value to `sum` without creating the list explicitly. `sum` will keep asking for numbers from the `genexpr` and stop when `StopIteration` is raised. This is faster than using a list comprehension.

If you have a very long sequence, and you use a list comprehension with the sum function, python will first take time to generate the entire list and then sum will again calculate the sum of all the elements. Using a generator expression with sum will reduce a lot of execution time because sum will get each value as soon as it is generated.

Comment: ”This is faster than using a list comprehension” ... only for large `n`

Comment: `(x for x in range(4))` is a generator, but is `x for x in range(4)`? That's what you're giving to `sum`, no?

Comment: @paxdiablo, apparently you can omit them, but only if generator expression is sole argument.

Comment: @paxdiablo `... for ... in ...` creates a generator whenever it is directly inside parentheses without any comma on either side.  They don’t need to be it’s “own” parentheses

Comment: @donkopotamus: Okay, that makes sense, `list(x for x in range(4))` works as well.

Comment: Most of these functions take generators as arguments as well. `max`, `min`, `list`, `tuple` etc.